# What alternative formats of the data dump would people be interested in?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Just as an example, when the last data dump was released I created a small C# program to convert it into Protocol Buffers format, but omitting the text. The text itself is rarely interesting for data mining purposes, but obviously takes up a lot of the space.

That raises three alternative formats immediately:

- Protocol Buffer (with .proto files obviously) including text
- Protocol Buffer excluding text
- XML excluding text

My guess is that not *very* many people are interested in the PB format, but if I were to also provide some appropriate tools to make it LINQ friendly, it may be fairly easy to create a [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) plugin or whatever. I find it easier to write LINQ than SQL :)

It might also be good to have a "diff" format so that people who have the previous data dumps can easily add the new ones. That would need to include deletions as well, of course - it wouldn't be a trivial thing to do (well, not for me anyway) but would make it a lot lighter each month.

I'm not suggesting that Jeff should be doing this by the way - although the no-text XML version would probably be welcome and relatively easy...

Comment: JSON            :P

Comment: yay proto ;-p   .

Comment: @Jon looks like is_cc_wiki missed the train, so i would expect more schema changes on post next month ...

Comment: CC Wiki will be in the next dump

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the diff format, its going to be really hard as there is at least one new fields in the upcoming dump (is community wiki)

Personally, I am happy with the current one XML file fits all solution, it does not take too long to download over bittorrent and I am able to [load it all into my local SQL server DB](http://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow/tree/master) in about 6 minutes.

Also, I find the text quite useful, for example I used the [text in the comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down).

I fear that introducing any complexity will reduce the teams inclination to work on this.

My biggest wish would be for a daily diff as opposed to a monthly diff. Cause that would allow for much faster feedback loops.

Comment: New fields would certainly merit new full dumps - but I don't expect the format to change *that* often. A daily diff would be interesting...