# Flag outdated CW comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-wiki, spam

It possible to get some moderator action to remove comments relating to Community-Wiki after a  question has been changed into a wiki question (either by the owner or the built in thresholds).

As an example see this question on superuser: [Windows annoyances](https://superuser.com/questions/5564/windows-annoyances). Here there are currently 20 comments and most of these are about turning the question into a Community-Wiki question rather than the actual question. Since this question is now CW all those comments are basically cruft. And worse they are up-voted so much that any real discussion is muted.

I would like to be able to flag those comments (as spam?) and get them deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, just flag this stuff for moderator attention, and we will take care of it.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Answer (score 3):

Even better, have people stop making those comments in the first place.

Comment: $chars = array('L', 'O'); while(1=1){ echo $chars[0]; echo $chars[1];} echo $chars[0];

Comment: `while(true) System.out.print("lo");`

Comment: Wrong ... you don't print out the last l.

Comment: how do you know?  It will never end..so actually....*head explodes*

Comment: for 0... -> $i { print 'lo' } *Perl 6*

Comment: shouldn't this be community wiki?

Comment: @Jeff ... Arrrrrrrgh!!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Those comments should really be flagged as abuse, for moderator attention.

[See this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).

In Particular, this is Jeff's stance:

> Do not bully users into community
>   wiki. You can offer a carrot in the
>   form of a comment that says "wow, I'd
>   love to vote this up if it was
>   community wiki" but downvoting and
>   other nagging is not appropriate.
>   (addendum: the community wiki flag
>   checkbox is not shown for new users
>   because they can't possibly understand
>   it, you may potentially be nagging new
>   users about a setting they don't even
>   have.)
>
> If you think something should be
>   community wiki then flag it for mod
>   attention with a comment to that
>   effect. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to flag those comments (as spam?) and get them deleted.

So do it then.

If you hover your mouse cursor over a comment, you'll see a little "flag" icon appear to the left of it. Click it.

If enough people do this, the comment will go away...

Comment: Haha I never thought of it that way. I was more worried the moderators would be wondering why I was flagging something. I like the 'just do it' attitude. :)