# Community Wiki checkbox missing in action

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

It looks like the Community Wiki checkbox is no longer appearing on the ask/edit question page, making it difficult to mark questions Community Wiki.

Where is it, and how is one supposed to mark a question as CW now?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

see:

- [Should the community wiki police be shut down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down)?
- [What can we do to make community wiki better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better)?

We removed that option globally from all questions.

If it really needs to be wiki, flag it for moderator attention, it was causing confusion and pain.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better which is a better statement of the reasoning behind the change IMO

Comment: I can understand if novice users might be confused by it, but at least make it a privilege for high-rep users such as trusted-users. Sometimes a question will get closed as a regular question, but [would work as CW](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/). Flagging to have a mod convert it could work, but why bother a mod and add it to the back of the mod queue when it could simply be done by consensus just like other things such as close-votes or suggested-edits?

Comment: Can users with 10k reputation also make a question a community wiki post?

Answer (score 9):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.