# Why can't I mark questions as community wiki?

Tags: bug, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better)
>   [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

There used to be a check box that would allow me to mark questions as "community wiki", below the editing area. I can no longer find that checkbox. This is consistent across all sites that I have tried (StackOverflow, SuperUser, meta.so, bicycles.se). It is consistent across several browsers: Google Chrome 6, Safari 5, Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.5, and Google Chrome 8 (dev channel) on Mac OS X 10.6.

The "community wiki" checkbox still shows up on answers, just not on questions, either for initially asking the question or for editing it. I have plenty of rep on all sites involved.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action