# What happened to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

It was pointed out to me, recently, that we are unable to mark our questions as Community Wiki anymore.  There are some questions where there isn't one right answer, but all answers are valuable, such as the [list of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books).  Could someone either explain why it was removed, or point me to the discussion that caused its removal?  I'm sure I missed the discussion.

Comment: The discussion that led to this implementation is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better). However, [you aren't the first one to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action).

Comment: You can accept answers even if the question is CW.

Comment: @Grace Note, thanks.  my searches were turning up empty.  @Kop, true, but that wasn't my point.

Answer (score 0):

If the question can't be objectively answered then it shouldn't be asked on Stack Overflow.  The question you reference would work better on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: good point. I hadn't thought of that.