# Where did the CW flag go?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

I was on the SQA private beta when I saw a question that really fit the bill for Community Wiki. I suggested it to him, and he asked how. I told him about the checkbox when he edits it.

Then I went to a question of mine to take a screenshot (picture is worth a thousand words, right?) Didn't see it. So I came onto SO, and went to some of my questions, and there's no CW box there either.

I tried searching for announcements or other people having this issue but couldn't.

Did CW kick the bucket and I just didn't know it?

Comment: See [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action), which explains that it has been removed on *questions*. Answers can still have it. You can read additional detail [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/) on how that decision came up.

Comment: Moderators can still convert questions to CW - so you *could* flag the question. However, this should be a very rare occurrence.

Comment: @Grace would you make that an answer so the question can be set as accepted? And thanks, that clears everything up. @ChrisF that's a good point. Yeah I don't plan to flag it, and especially being in private beta for only 3 more hours, there's no doubt a moderator will be around soon anyway.

Comment: I'm kinda voting to close as a duplicate, actually. Which, for the record, will not affect your accept rate as closed questions are not counted.

Comment: @Grace all the same to me. Thanks for the links :)