# I want to post my question as community wiki. How can I do that?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I can't find the option to post a question in community wiki mode. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Mysticial, What can I use it for?

Comment: I don't know. I'm asking you. Why do you want to post a question as a wiki? You must have a reason do so if you're asking this question.

Comment: The option for CW on questions has not existed in [a very long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action), for different reasons. Read about Community Wiki [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: But @Mysticial is right to ask - why do you need it?

Comment: If you really insist, first post the question as usual then flag it for moderator attention, choose "Other" and explain why exactly you want such a thing. Keep in mind your request might be rejected though.

Comment: Thanx everyone for the clarification.

Comment: *[Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581)* seems to be the real duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a question CW when posting it. The option to do so has been removed a [long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action) as it invited the kind of questions that we do not normally want (recommendations, open-ended, discussion making posts). It was also abused as a way to ensure one didn't lose reputation for a bad question, so was taken away.

A question can still be made CW in one of several processes - multiple edits being the main one (either by the OP or others), though you can flag the post to moderator attention and ask for it to be made CW - you would need a really good reason for that though.

See [What are Community Wiki Posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for details.