# Creating an FAQ tag like the one that is available on meta for each stackexchange

Tags: discussion, site-faq

Do you think it's neccesary to create an faq for stackoverflow for instance that answers frequently asked questions about programming?
I think it would be very useful to do such a thing in order to avoid duplicated answers and to pre answer those kind of questions.

What do you guys think?

Comment: This is kinda sorta already being done. I think polygenelubricants is in charge. See [the question asking for permission to create FAQs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62695/permission-to-start-a-series-of-advanced-regex-articles), a recent one about [a C++ FAQ on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) and [this one about etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/should-c-faq-tagged-threads-be-made-cw).

Comment: I am asking because this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212923/best-practices-when-creating-a-server-client-application is considered too vague. I consider this a very useful question and an answer that says "just don't do it" is not good enough. I really want to learn how it's done.