# What's new on CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I read somewhere that Community Wiki is dead? Why and what exactly does 'dead' mean here?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't dead, but it is no longer possible for users to create Community Wiki *questions*.

Check the freshly updated FAQ: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Official announcement: [Should the community wiki police be shut down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)

Comment: Don't forget to include [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better), which highlights all the discussion which led to this implementation.