# flag for moderator attention when question might be community wiki?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki, moderation

Is it ok to flag for moderator attention if I think, a question should be a community wiki?
For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539990/ios-sdk-first-advices-for-beginners/4540136#4540136).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Since the [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183), moderators are the only ones who can make a question community wiki.