# Redesign "lots of answers" JS confirm dialog to use Stacks stylized popups instead

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, popups

Currently, when attempting to answer questions with lots of answers ([usually 30 but configurable per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86893/377214)), users are shown the following generic JS confirmation prompt (from one's browser, in this case Edge):

> [image: JS confirmation prompt warning of 30+ answers]

In my opinion, this looks rather drab, and in many cases users just skip the prompt without bothering to read it. It also doesn't fit well with SE's design goals. Finally, if users' browsers are configured to automatically skip past these prompts (which is what happens if the checkbox depicted on the bottom above is checked), users will never see this prompt.

To help align better with SE's latest design goals, and to try and reduce the numbers of users whose eyes gloss past, muscle memories skip, or browsers automatically bypass generic warning messages, I'd like to propose that it be replaced with a Stacks design popup like the following:

> [image: Styled popup prompting the same thing]

I'd also like to take the opportunity to propose a wording change: this prompt is also shown to anonymous (logged-out) users, who see an "improve this answer" link instead of "edit", so if the user is logged out the dialog should change to say "'improve this answer' link".