# Should this answer really be "community wiki"?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Evidently the asker of the question made a lot of edits, and inadvertently turned it into a "community wiki" question. That means my answer was also marked community wiki. That just doesn't seem right.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129895/5987

Comment: That is odd behavior, and definitely [not documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts?rq=1). I wonder if this is actually a bug?

Comment: @jmac yes it is: "An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki"

Comment: @Sha well color me illiterate (BRUEENPLE)

Comment: @jmac "•The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner" - actually documented, the question is if it should be so.

Comment: @Łukasz -- if the question was edited 10 times by the original owner, that doesn't explain why the answer would be marked CW (though the portion stated by Sha definitely covers this)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's very little support in the system for CW questions with non-CW answers (or the reverse of this). Something to keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently an undocumented feature with very poor warning for the souls exposed to it.

I posted over at the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) to see if my answer would become a community wiki. When I clicked "add answer" I got the following message:

> [image: lots of answers warning]

Now you didn't get one of these because you are the only answer on that question (for questions with lots of answers, it seems you have to click the 'Add an Answer' button and get the above warning). Instead you got an answer box that looks like this:

> [image: cw answer]

Note something missing? This is what a normal question looks like:

> [image: non-cw answer]

In this case, the original post was converted to a community wiki prior to you answering:

The revision that made it CW was at [3:36:09 zulu time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19064318/12).

> [image: offending edit]

Your answer rolled in at [4:13:13 zulu time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19129895/1)

> [image: answer timing]

Since there is no warning, and you didn't realize that the CW box wasn't there, you were unaware that your answer would be automatically wiki-ed <strike>(and I couldn't find anywhere this [feature](/questions/tagged/feature) is documented)</strike>.

It would be much friendlier if you either got a warning (as you do when there are many answers, though including a warning that your post will automatically be community wiki'd), or at least if it kept the community wiki checkbox and just locked it (any click bringing up a nice little box saying, *"Answers to community wiki posts are automatically created as community wikis"*) or the sort. But that would be a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: nice explanation, but why I don't see community wiki checkbox when asking questions??

Comment: @Jason no idea. It seems to be status-by-design though.

Comment: @Jason we can't mark question as CW, only answers.

Comment: oh then the rules that I read were all about questions not answers (how a question can be converted to wiki)...

Comment: @JasonOOO - It is [changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/187824). So now if you think your question needs CW status just flag it.

Comment: @Jason and jmac - I've added some missing details to the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/152859). :)

Comment: Thanks @Sha! I added the fact that the check box is not displayed if the question is already marked community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You saw before posting the answer the question turned into Community Wiki so  you knew the "risk" of not getting reputation for it.

So if you post just for reputation, don't answer questions marked as Community Wiki.

Your answer is CW because the question was CW at the time of posting, that's how things work. I don't see any reason to change this and if the answer is really great, you can still earn reputation from bounties. (I sometimes reward good answers with a bounty so pretty sure others also do this)

Last but not least, the question itself became CW due to many edits. If you think those edits are all justified and not made just to bump with minor changes feel free to flag and ask to undo the CW status of the question. Not 100% sure it will also undo your answer status, but then you can ask for it.

Comment: No actually I didn't see that it was community wiki before I posted, I discovered it after. And I'm not desperate for the points, but I do use it to know when someone found my answer to their liking.